# Is there any reason why this results in NaN instead of the str generated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Why does this result in NaN instead of a string?

```py
df['rnd'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(random.randint(0,9999)).zfill(4))

rnd
---
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

```py
df.dtypes
Rnd                 object
```

Comment: Why are you even using `apply` here? Just create the series and assign it.  You aren't acting on anything in your `df`

Comment: @user3483203 It's not like `Rnd` is the only thing in the dataset; it just appears that way in my question.

Comment: But you aren't accessing any data in your dataframe, so using apply doesn't make sense.  The `x` in your lambda function is ignored, this is just code smell.

Comment: @user3483203 I'm just trying to add a new column with a random value; I know about x being a row and it shouldn't be there; but I don't know what to use instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a new random column (as zero-padded strings), you can vectorize it with numpy's [`randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) (which accepts a `size`) and [`str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html), e.g.:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4, 3)))

df['rnd'] = np.random.randint(0, 999, size=len(df))
df['rnd'] = df['rnd'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)
```

Output:

```
          0         1         2   rnd
0  0.696305  0.624101  0.235630  0056
1  0.437783  0.558600  0.451735  0913
2  0.061021  0.633813  0.008970  0509
3  0.944699  0.713951  0.478524  0088
```

Answer (score 0):

u need applymap not apply

```
df['rnd'] = df.applymap(lambda x: str(random.randint(0,9999)).zfill(4))
```

and this is the result

```
0    0179
1    4545
2    8510
3    3316
Name: rnd, dtype: object
```

if you want to use apply method then u need t specify the column to act on :

```
df["rnd"] = df.rnd.apply(lambda x: str(random.randint(0,9999)).zfill(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

It needed an `axis`.

```py
df['rnd'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(random.randint(0,9999)).zfill(4), axis=1)
```